# cannot go back to previous fragments or activity with single tap

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to go back to my previous `activity/fragment` when back is pressed.
            Suppose  I have my main fragment as main screen, from there i go to an activity.now when i press back.. it quits the app.. i need to go to main fragment. how to do this? i need to go back to the
            main fragment. as normal back works. but i don't know where i have made a mistake:

my java code is here.. or try the app..

code from activity:

```
@Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // handle arrow click here
                if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                    finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                    return;
                }
                this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
                    }
               }, 1000);
            }
```

the above is my code from my `activity`.i don't know where my mistake is. may be i made mistake in `onoptionsitemselected` ? or other thing maybe.

`finish()` does it needs a return true as i found out on other questions ? earlier when pressing back from 1 activity to another worked properly.. but when i used fragments it was an issue..

Comment: add your full java code where u using this piece of code.

Comment: @ Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
finish(); }
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@ Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
super.onBackPressed();
return;
}
this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@ Override
public void run() {
doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
}
 }, 1000);
  }

Comment: here @W4R10CK  ..

Comment: done @W4R10CK  ..

Comment: are u trying to use _double tap to exit_ ?

Comment: yes... but single tap should take u to last activity/fragment right >?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    FragmentManager mgr = getFragmentManager();

    if (mgr.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        mgr.popBackStack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

You will need to adjust it a bit for your desired "double click to exit" behavior.

Comment: the issue persist only when back is pressed from activity to fragment